# I need an advise about implementing a truncate option in endpoint

Tags: endpoint, truncate, prisma

I developed a backend using Prisma as ORM. Recently I had to truncate (more than once) some tables.
I did it directly with SQL queries, so I'm thinking to include a truncate option to the Delete endpoint.
It's recommended to do that? I'm asking overall because of possibly security issues.
If so, what's better, a **$queryRaw** with a truncate or a **deleteMany({where: {}})**.
I know if I want to delete CASCADE I have to add it to the ON DELETE on the foreign keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on your application and use case, but either `queryRaw` or `deleteMany` will work.

If you would use `deleteMany` then all the records will be deleted in a transaction as mentioned [here](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/transactions#batchbulk-operations) which depending on your use case could be favourable.